# Stop a function from being called without modifying it?

Tags: assembly, inline-assembly

The title may seem confusing but, how would I be able to modify a subroutine without modifying its memory?

What I'm trying to do is basically NOP the subroutine (*effectively* making it useless) without modifying the memory or produce something equivalent to that ... Is that possible?

Comment: I suppose you could NOP all the places that call it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Unix/Linux, and it's in a shared library, use [symbol interposition](http://www.macieira.org/blog/2012/01/sorry-state-of-dynamic-libraries-on-linux/) to provide a do-nothing definition that you load first.  (e.g. via `LD_PRELOAD`).

Otherwise I don't see any option other than modifying every call-site, if you can't modify the call target.

You tagged this as "inline-assembly".  Does that mean you can recompile the whole program?  If so, then do that and use preprocessor tricks to define the calls into no-ops.

Comment: Sorry about that tag, I meant to tag it as C++ (don't ask); Is it possible that I could use the **VirtualProtect** function on the function and change it to PAGE_NOACCESS so that the application can not access that subroutine or am I missing a general concept about the VirtualProtect function?

Comment: @Nope.avi: That looks like the Windows equivalent of `mprotect(2)`, to change the read/write/execute bits of a virtual page.  Nothing specific to C++, but ok, that's fine.  That would make your program crash if it calls the function, or any other function in the same 4k page.  That's fine if you just want to verify that your program *doesn't* call the function, except for the collateral damage to nearby functions.

Comment: Windows dynamic linking doesn't support symbol interposition (with the advantage of less overhead), but you might still be able to do some DLL tricks.  I'm not a Windows guy.  Maybe you could make a special version of your normal DLL that had a different version of that function?